# REPL error with Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I'm using REPL with sublime text 3 (latest version as of today) and I'm coding in python 3.4. As far as I understand the documentation on REPL if do: tools>sublimeREPL>python>python-RUN current file
then I should run the code I have typed in using REPL. However when I do this I get an error pop up saying:

FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.',None,2)

I get this error whatever the code I typed in is (I tried print ("Hello World") on its own and also big long programs I've made before)
Can someone please help me with this and explain what the problem is, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem. This is most probably due to the default location of python. If you are running portable python,

```
{
...
"default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH}:\\Programming\\Python\\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\\App\\"}
...
 }
```

Otherwise,

```
{
"default_extend_env": {"PATH":"C:\\python27\\"},
}
```

would suffice. This code is to be pasted in:

```
Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeREPL -> Settings - User
```

Comment: Is the portable python link supposed to point to the entire Portable Python file or the Python.exe?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, when I installed REPL for the first time. Now, that could sound crazy, but the way to solve the problem (at least, the trick worked for me!) is to restart once Sublime Text 3.

**Update**: As pointed out by Mark in the comments, apparently you could have to restart Sublime more than once to solve the problem.

Comment: Unbelievably this actually worked for me also with the Clojure REPL.  I think maybe the list of binaries in PATH is read at startup and not refreshed until you restart.

Comment: I tried this once and it didnt work, tried second time worked a charm :)